# Java AffineTransform Translation isn't working

Tags: java, translation, affinetransform

**UPDATE**
Turns out I'm just tired. There isn't any problem here sorry for wasting your time. Don't worry I flagged this for a moderator to look at.

My problem is that when I translate a bufferedimage in java it moves up and down while im translating it on the x axis. 
For a better understanding of my problem watch this:
     http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stwi1qVakp4

So what is my setup:
 Well, What i do is in my rendering method I have:

```
AffineTransform.translate(player_dx,0);
```

Then I'd have a keylistener that is like:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        player_dx = 1;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        player_dx = -1;
    }

}

 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        player_dx = 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        player_dx = 0;
    }

}
```

I think this is happening because when i rotate it changes the x, y coordinates so if it's 90 degrees the x and y change. I just don't know if I can bypass that.

Just tell me if you need to know anything else. Thanks, Javaman111

Comment: Yeah, you've got problems with your code, but it's likely in code that you're not showing us.

Comment: Nope. I think it is because when i rotate it changes the x, y coordinates so if it's 90 degrees the x and y change. I just don't know if I can bypass that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the code for the arm, not the affine transform for the character. It probably has to do with how much your moving the arm on each axis or you may have reversed your X and Y by mistake.

Comment: Like I said, the problem is in code not shown, but he obviously doesn't believe me.

Comment: ? I believe it is that code. All I have to render the image is g2.drawImage(rightarm, rightarmtransform, null); I think the program is switching the x/y pos for the translation because I tested it once with it rotated 90 degrees and when i tried to translate it on the x axis it translated on the y axis

Comment: NEVERMIND. I just had a derp moment. It is fine. I thought the arm was going down but it was fine. Sorry to waste your time lol